# No se instala apk

Tags: android, android-studio, instalacion

Estoy desarrollando una app en Java para Android.

A la hora de probar la aplicación (haciendo un debug) sobre un smartphone, se instala y se ejecuta bien.

Mi problema viene a la hora de instalar la aplicación en producción. Genero la apk firmada sin problemas (Android Studio no me muestra errores ni warnings), la paso al smartphone (por USB o bluetooth) y a la hora de instalarla me da error y no se instala.

No me muestra ningún mensaje de error y como he dicho antes, si la "debugeo" sobre el smartphone no hay problema pero el apk firmado y definitivo no se instala.

He descartado el tema de las versiones de android puesto que, como he dicho, la puedo emular en el dispositivo.

Alguna idea? Al no mostrarme mensaje de error no puedo indagar más por internet.

Comment: Lo que yo creo: cuando generas un build de la APK lo haces en un modo Debug, de manera que no hay ningún problema en instalarla en tus dispositivos. Cuando la firmas, me parece que debe pasar por la Playstore para poder ser instalada en los dispositivos.

Comment: ¿Has probado en desinstalar la app que usabas para "debuggear" en tu movíl y luego instalar la firmada?

Comment: aveces los paquetes son distintos por ser debug o ser release, como dice David, desinstalando la de debug e instalando la nueva deberia funcionar

Comment: Yo revisaría el manifest, que no tengas nada raro ahí con respecto al debug y demás. Creo que alguna vez me pasó algo así, y era debido a cuestiones de permisos en el mismo dispositivo, en las opciones avanzadas, que tenía algún permiso apagado. No sabría decirte exactamente cuál era porque no lo recuerdo. Otra cosa es que debes estar muy atento a la pantalla del dispositivo cuando estás instalando el APK, a veces abre una pantalla de autorización que dura unos segundos y debes aceptar para que se instale. Si dejas que esa pantalla desaparezca no podrás instalar.

Comment: Inteto contestar a todos comentarios. SebastianPaduano, se puede instalar una apk firmada en producción pasándola por usb. David_helo he probado a desinstalar la app en debug pero nada. GastónSaillén no me ha funcionado desinstalar la de debug. A.Cedano creo que va por ahí la historia, algo debe haber en el manifest que me provoca ese error. Voy a conectar el smartphone a Android Studio que creo que lo puedo utilizar para ver el log del móvil.

Answer (score 1):

Para explicar porque tienes este problema recuerda que:

La aplicación que firmas para `Google Play Store` usa un `Keystore` diferente a el `Keystore` usado cuando subes la aplicación desde `Android Studio` a tu emulador o dispositivo.

El problema se genera cuando tienes una versión instalada creada por diferente `Keystore`, por lo tanto pueden existir estas condiciones:

- Si tienes instalada la versión de debug y tratas de subir la firmada para la Google Play Store, se mostrará un error y no se podrá instalar la aplicación puesto que fueron firmadas con distinto Keystore.
- Si tienes instalada la versión de debug y tratas de subir la firmada para la Google Play Store, y ambas **tienen diferente `versionCode`** en realidad Google Playstore mostrará que ya se encuentra instalada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Si tienes instalada la versión firmada para Google Play Store y tratas de instalar desde `Android Studio`, marcará el error `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK` pero mostrará un mensaje, donde preguntará si decides desinstalar la actual aplicación ( Google Play Store ) e instalar la versión de `Android Studio`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

La primera condición es la que estas experimentando, en este caso la solución es que debes desinstalar la versión de la aplicación que se encuentra instalada.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys. Lo primero gracias por la ayuda. Mi caso no es ninguno de los que comentas puesto que en el smartphone que intento instalar la aplicación, no la tengo instalada anteriormente. No la intento instalar desde Android Studio, firmo la app pero la intento instalar pasándola por usb, aún no la he subido a play store para depurarla bien.

Answer (score 1):

He hallado la solución (aunque no se porque se producía el problema).

He sacado la solución de la siguiente pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979625/android-studio-signed-apk-app-not-installing

Para arreglar el fallo, como comenta la respuesta que he puesto el link, era marcar dos opciones en Android Studio a la hora de generar el instalador.

[image]

Comment: He hallado la respuesta pero realmente no se porque se producía el fallo.